# JavaScript - Store Form Text in Local Storage

Tags: javascript

So for this programming assignment we're supposed have users fill out a form and keep their input in local storage as they type and until they submit the form.

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" onkeyup="StoreText()">
```

is part of my HTML form, and I have the following function:

```
<script>
    function StoreText() {
    var name = document.getElementById("name");
    localStorage.setItem("name", name);
    }
</script>
```

However, I'm using the Chrome inspector to view the local storage and I don't see anything there. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: What have you done to debug the problem? Is the event handler executed at all? Hint: You are trying to store a DOM element in local storage. That won't work. You have to get the value of the `<input>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try storing name.value instead of name.

Comment: Please **explain** why the OP should "try" that.

Comment: It seemed like an easy problem to fix since I assume you can't store an element in the localStorage, hardly worth explaining.

Comment: Apparently the OP is a beginner. I think they will be grateful for every bit of information. Not to mention future visitors. No one learns anything from a single line "do A instead of B" answer. The OP might not be aware that `name` is a DOM element or that you can't store DOM elements in local storage. So it's indeed very useful for point that out.

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle: http://liveweave.com/z71PS8

This is how localStorage works.

Firs you have to tell localStorage to getItem (this will be retrieved later with setItem which locally stores your value)

```
if ( localStorage.getItem('Data')) {
  $("#name").val(localStorage.getItem('Data')); 
}
```

Now you save your value with the following...

```
localStorage.setItem('Data', $("#name").val());
```

You may also want to see [Using Local Storage for Appended HTML](http://codepen.io/mikethedj4/pen/eAmbp).

**The JavaScript/JQuery:**

```
if ( localStorage.getItem('Data')) {
  $("#name").val(localStorage.getItem('Data')); 
}
$("#name").keyup(function() {
  localStorage.setItem('Data', $("#name").val());
});
```

**The HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="name">
```

[Here's](http://liveweave.com/0QEtvr) a pure Javascript/non JQuery Solution